# Skipping .DS_Store files when copying between two external drives

Tags: finder, backup

There are [quite a few](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=DS_Store) questions on `.DS_Store` files already, but none seem to answer my problem.

I have an external hard drive with a dozen of ~ 50 GB backup folders. When I try to copy these folders to a new external hard drive by drag-and-drop, it fails because

> .DS_Store already exists and could not copied.
>   [Stop]

To circumvent this issue, **how can I skip copying .DS_Store files when copying between two hard drives?**

A Terminal command solution certainly exists, but I am not well-versed enough in `cp` to find it myself. All help appreciated!

P.S. Both disks are Mac OS X Extended (Journaled).

Comment: Are you copying to an existing directory? I assume otherwise there would not be a .DS_Store file o the target, but in this case are you overwriting any other files

Comment: I'm copying directly to the disk root, not to an existing directory, and there are no existing files on the target, so there is no overwrite.

Comment: The error messages says there is a .DS_Store file on the target - what does `ls -al` show on the target?

Comment: `ls- al` shows nothing particular: I presume it's a corrupted file issue (the `.DS_Store` files have been causing trouble for some time now).

Comment: SO where is the .DS_Store you are trying to overwrite?

Comment: I don't know that, otherwise I would have deleted the file manually. It took place as I described it: I dropped a large archive folder at the root of a new hard drive, and it repeatedly failed midway because of the message posted above. I cannot say which `.DS_Store` file among the hundreds in my archive was causing trouble, so skipping them was the best strategy.

Comment: I am asking about what is on the target you say there are non, but the code says there is, I suspect you are not actually doing what you think you are

Comment: However rsync is often the better way anyway

Comment: Making sure that there was _nothing_ on target was my first move, but the problem occurred _inside_ the archive, which is large and therefore likely to contain errors. And yes, `rsync` saved my day :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try `rsync -rv --exclude=.DS_Store <source> <destination>` from terminal.

for example

`rsync -rv --exclude=.DS_Store ~/Documents /Volumes/Backup/Documents`

will do:

- (-r) recursive (copy everything below ~/Documents)
- (-v) verbose (tell you what it's doing)
- (--exclude) excluding any file named `.DS_Store`
- from `~/Documents`
- to  `/Volumes/Backup/Documents`

`rsync` is like a suped up `cp` command with way more options, most specifically `--exclude`

Comment: That is _exactly_ what I was looking for, thank you!